# 'pytube module not found' when code is run on a code editor as .ipynb file but runs without error in Powershell as a .py file

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, virtual-environment, pytube, code-editor

I have created a virtual environment to process youtube videos. Having installed the packages required I ran the base code in Powershell and cmd and it works well but the same code returns a 'pytube module not found' error when I use VS Code or Jupyterlab from the same virtual environment.

I have checked the list of packages and pytube module is included. I also tried to re-install from the code editor and it confirms that 'requirement already satisfied'